# Client GUI blocked due to socket.recv()

Tags: python, blocking, tcpsocket

I have a very minor question regarding Python TCP `socket.recv()` being a blocking call. I am making an IRC though Python (assignment), I'm nearing the end but came across a small bump in the road. I'm trying to have the server push updates of a dict containing `{"ChannelName": [users]}` and I'm serializing/deserializing with JSON (So my problem isn't the actual message). I send/receive everything just fine. My biggest issue is not getting blocked on `socket.recv()`.

What I've done is something similar (Excuse my pseudo code):

```
async def getchannelsandusers(self):
     # Code to get serialized json

def sendchannelsandusers(self):
     # for each user send the code from self.getchannelsandusers

def threadtoupdate(self):
     t = threading.Timer(5, self.sendchannelsandusers)
     t.start()

def funcwhereblockis(self):
     self.threadtoupdate()
     usermessage = socket.recv(size).decode('utf8') # <- gets stuck here only updates once
```

My final goal is to continue updating the client GUI with the channels and users in the channel through the `socket.send()` located in the server side.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is `funchwereblockis` called on the client side? And it would help to see the code where the server sends the information, since this call blocking could mean either the client is trying to read when it shouldn't or that the server didn't send a message the client expected.

Comment: Also, in `threadtoupdate` you create a timer which immediately goes out of scope. I'm not sure what happens in this case, but I'd recommend checking that it'll still do what you want.

Comment: I believe it wait's until it reaches the size for a socket.recv(size).

Comment: No, it does not wait for all bytes to be read. `recv()` reads *at most* `size` bytes of data from the socket. It may return fewer.